# Unicode error with Solr

Tags: xml, unicode, solr

I have an index that takes textual description and places it in the index.
I build XML object to pass them on to Solr where indexing is done. Now when I search in chinese text, I get back question marks for the indexed text whose XML was fine.

Any idea where the problem could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using C#'s weblclient, had to enable unicode encoding prior to sending it to Solr.

Answer (score 1):

Check the actual text going over the wire to SOLR using a tool like Fiddler.  I would bet that you are not sending what you think you are sending.

Comment: Actually i was using a C# webclient that needed encoding to be enabled. Nailed it finally. Thanks for the tip.